# using google auth in flutter and displaying usernames and images

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying to get the username of google account that  user used in his sign in and I want to display it as text not print can you help.this is the code:

```
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
    idToken: gSA.idToken, accessToken: gSA.accessToken);
print("User Name : ${user.displayName}");
return user;}
```

and the part that I want to put the username in as a text is here

```
new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Log In"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.account_box),
          onTap: () => _signIn()
              .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
              .catchError((e) => print(e)),
          subtitle: new Text(display username here),
        ),
```

Comment: which text does not print? and what does it print instead ?

Comment: we need more information to help you. does the signin popup happen? if not then you probably installed the google sign in plugin wrong.  if not, like what aziza said - what gets printed on tap?

Comment: everything works correctl byt  I want to display the username in a text form

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

Make a variable '***name***' and then use the following code.

```
String name = 'Log In';

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
  FirebaseUser _user;

    Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async {

        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken
        );

        setState(() {
            name = user.displayName.toString();
        });

        return user;
  }
```

Using **[setState()](http://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)** function solves your problem :)

Comment: I have tried it but in my class all the instances must be final, so i cant use string because setState will not be defined

Comment: Any specific reason for that? Anyways other way could be routing to a new scene or class and passing the _auth to that class and use the same to display name.

Comment: why orgnizations emails aren't showing in google auth, example: @univ.dz even though it is based on Gmail but it doesn't show as an option